# Convert file to binary data and back in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file

I have an image from `<input />` stored in javascript `File`. I would like to convert this file into binary string (not base64) and these binary data back into the image.

```js
const file = input.files[0]
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
reader.onloadend = () => {
    const binaryString = reader.result // Binary string.
    const newFile = new File([binaryString], file.name, { type: file.type }) // Re-create file from binary data.
}
```

Anyway, if I create data url for `newFile` (`FileReader.readAsDataURL`), download a file from this url and open it, I will get an error message:

> Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xef 0xbf

Where am I doing mistake in this process? When I apply `readAsDataUrl` on original `file`, everything is ok. So problem could be either `readAsBinaryString(file)` or `new File([binaryString])`.

Also, because `readAsBinaryString` is deprecated, I tried `readAsArrayBuffer`, but the result was same.

Comment: what happens if you do `{type:"UTF-8"}` instead of `{ type: file.type }`?

Comment: @AlanOmar It seems this doesn't have any effect. For types `UTF-8`, `file.type` or `image/jpeg` same result.